# C# padLeft, not adding pad

Tags: c#

I am writing a method to format a phone number and also add padding to the beginning if there are less than 10 digits in the initial array. I am only failing use cases where less than 10 digits are input and my method is clearly not adding the padding. The most common mistake is using the wrong padcount parameter. I am sure I am missing something simple.

```
public static string CreatePhoneNumber(int[] numbers)
  {
    string numbas = string.Join("", numbers);

    string ammendNumbas = numbas;

    char pad = '0';

    if ( numbas.Length < 10) 
    {
        ammendNumbas = numbas.PadLeft(10, pad);
    }

    string formatString = "(###) ###-####";
    var returnValue = Convert.ToInt64(ammendNumbas)
                 .ToString(formatString.Substring(0,ammendNumbas.Length+4))
                 .Trim();
     return returnValue;
  }
```

Comment: `ToInt64` removes leading zeros

Answer (score 6):

When you use Convert.ToInt64 you would be removing all padding because padding can only be applied to strings. You would need to not convert the value back to an integer after applying padding.

I think what you want is this:

```
public static string CreatePhoneNumber(int[] numbers)
{
   Int64 numbas = Convert.ToInt64(string.Join("", numbers));
   return numbas.ToString("(000) 000-0000");
}
```

Comment: Ok! I had a feeling my problem was centered around that Int64 conversion. Thanks!

Comment: @JeffLongo Also your code can be significantly simplified, See above edit.

Comment: Most certainly! I'm still at the bumble my way through stage. Seeing everyones solutions is definitely eye opening and helpful!

Comment: Your bumbling included an interesting simplification as well, though! I might not have thought to use string.Join directly on an array of integers. I would have thought you'd have had to convert the array of integers to an array of strings first, which would have involved a few more lines of code. On the other hand, I would not have passed a phone number in as an array of integers in the first place. :) I would consider whether you can just accept the phone number as a string or an integer or an array of strings because accepting an array of integers may require callers to do more work.

Comment: I think the input of the array was only put there as an added hurdle. Definitely not the ideal input hahah

Answer (score 3):

What BlueMonk said is correct but you can do the padding with String.Format

```
  public static string CreatePhoneNumber(int[] numbers)
  {
      string phoneNumberStr = string.Join("", numbers);

      var phoneNumber = Convert.ToInt64(phoneNumberStr);

      return String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", phoneNumber);
  }
```

This is not tested but should work.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `Convert.ToInt64`, the information of leading zeroes is lost. You can use substrings of your padded string representation to extract the digit groups:

```
public static string CreatePhoneNumber(int[] numbers)
{
    var numberString = string.Join("", numbers);
    var paddedNumbers = numberString.PadLeft(10, '0');
    return $"({paddedNumbers.Substring(0, 3)}) {paddedNumbers.Substring(3, 3)}-{paddedNumbers.Substring(6)}";
}
```